# Javascript Injection on my WordPress Site

Tags: javascript, hacked

My WordPress site is redirecting the user to some ad sites. It has generated some random clicks and each click redirects to the ad site. Also, now my site is labeled as dangerous by google. I have scanned my site on multiple to check for the source cause, All I could figure out was there was some

[[eval(String.fromCharCode(118, 97 , ... ]] which in turns compiles to generate a l

I have check each page on my website manually and each table in my database but I could find it. Can anyone help to find the code so that I can remove that and resubmit my site.

Comment: Install wordfence security plugin and scan your side it will display the list of file.

Comment: @EvinceDevelopment if the site is already infected, then there’s no point in installing Wordfence or any other of such plugins - malware can easily change behavior of such plugins...

Comment: If you have access to all of your files and database and you can't find it then I don't think we can help you remotely sorry, since we don't have that access.

Comment: @EvinceDevelopment I did that, the scan from the plugin is clear and none of the file is shown to be corrupted.

Comment: @Ifrah is still redirecting the user to some ad sites?

Comment: yes @EvinceDevelopment 
http://www.euphoriatravels.com/ is the site